# "Speech bubble" notifications

Tags: c#, .net, c++, mfc, notifications

I'm trying to get a notification to pop up something like these bubbles in an **MFC application**:

[image: unused icons bubble image]

[image: caps lock still on image]
<sub>(source: [humanized.com](http://www.humanized.com/weblog/images/caps_lock_indication.png))</sub>

I'm currently making an interface mockup in C# to show some stakeholders, so it would be nice to have it there too.

It doesn't necessarily have to be speech-bubble-esque: it could be something like a tooltip - but it does have to appear without mouse-over

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Just found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/balloonshow.aspx?display=PrintAll) on CodeProject. Downloaded the sample and it works well actually. I'm going to add this to my own code repository; never know when I may need this!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RobMisNotifyWindow.aspx) (C#)  :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a standard windows mechanism (since XP), they're called **Balloon Tooltips**. Depending on where you want to display the balloon, you can use `CEdit`'s [`ShowBalloonTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398687.aspx) method or [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159.aspx) API.

There's [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class in Windows Forms, but I don't know about TextBox, you would probably have to use interop.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - could that be because I'm under VS2005?

Comment: Yes, probably, CEdit's ShowBalloonTip might have been introduced in VS2008. You can use CEdit's HWND and do it in pure API. There's a Edit_ShowBalloonTip macro.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

ToolTip myTip = new ToolTip; // create tooltip
myTip.IsBaloon = true; // give it a round shape
myTip.SetToolTip( myTool, "You're hovering above myTool." ); // register popup message for 'myTool'
...
myTip.Show(myTool, "Forced modal pop-up.", 1000 ); // display pop up message for 1 sec at 'myTool'
```