# Pop-Up "speech bubble" not with actions, not on a map

Tags: android, dialog, quickaction

I am trying to implement a popup dialog which resembles the [QuickAction Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/). The difference is I would like to have a vertically scrollable textview within the pop up instead of all of these actions.

This [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593341/speech-bubble-notifications) is EXACTLY what I want, but this question pertains to C#.

I have found tons of examples dealing with Maps but nothing without maps. I am trying to have the user press a button, and have the speech bubble appear from that button.

```
ctInfoButton = new ImageButton( this );
ctInfoButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
         // Pop up code initialized here.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what u want is an android '9-patch' bubble that will accept text in its expandible area.

see these [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399612/create-a-chat-bubble-in-android)

In general, you need to create the layout enclosing the 9-patch. That requires a separate set of graphics tools to create the special, expandable image that will go into your resources folder.

once youve created the 9-patch image, you can define a logical overlay of text area that expands on the image. You get a reference on that text field, set it to the text value that you want to fill the bubble and it will expand as required to enclose the text with the bubble image.